# Memory Reference for Two Object

Tags: java

I have doubt regarding the java object memory allocation, I tried one example but looks like my understanding is not correct. Need help to get clarification on that.

Giving below example for more explanation,

```
Example 
Class A { int a; B b; public B getB( return this.b); public void setB(B b){this.b=b}}

Class B { 
Float amount; 
String type; 
B(Float amount,String type){this.amount=amount; this.type=type}
public B getType( return this.type); 
public void setType(String type){this.type=type} 
@override 
public boolean equals(Object o){
   if(this==0) return true;
   if(this!=null && this.getClass()!=o.getClass()) return false;
   B that = (B)o;
   return this.amount== that.amount;
} 
@override 
public int hashCode(){
    int result=0;
    result=31*result+(this.amount!=null?this.amount.hashCode():0);
    return result;
}

Class C{
   public static void main(String s[]){
     A aObj1 = new A(2,new B(10f,"a1"));
     System.out.println(" Befor change :: aObj1.getB().getType() ==>"+ aObj1.getB().getType());

     A aObj2 = new A(2,new B(10f,"a2"));
     System.out.println(" Befor change :: aObj2.getB().getType() ==>"+ aObj2.getB().getType());

     aObj2.getB().setType("a11");
     System.out.println(" After change :: aObj1.getB().getType() ==>"+ aObj1.getB().getType());
     System.out.println(" After change :: aObj2.getB().getType() ==>"+ aObj2.getB().getType());


   }
}
}
```

Output I am getting below::

```
 Befor change :: aObj1.getB().getType() ==> a1
 Befor change :: aObj2.getB().getType() ==> a2

 After change :: aObj1.getB().getType() ==> a1
 After change :: aObj2.getB().getType() ==> a11
```

My Question is that as per my understanding both B reference in different A object, should point same memory location, because I have override equal and hashCode. Then why changing reference B of object aObj2 is not reflecting the B reference of aObj1.

Need response on this, I am very eager to know where my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to post real code that compiles, instead of this approximation. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks Khelwood, for giving an idea to post question in better way.

Comment: please let me know , where I am getting wrong for this memory concept through java.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different `B` objects!

```
 A aObj1 = new A(2,new B(10f,"a1")); // <----- you created one here
 System.out.println(" Befor change :: aObj1.getB().getType() ==>"+ aObj1.getB().getType());

 A aObj2 = new A(2,new B(10f,"a2")); // and another one here
```

Basically, each time you use the `new` keyword, you are creating a new object.

So changing the `B` object referenced by `aObj2` does not affect the `B` object referenced by `aObj1`.

Comment: K, then as per you java not taking help of hashCode method to allocate memory, in that case which is responsible to allocate memory for object ?

Comment: The JVM, I suppose... Java programmers don't really need to worry about memory management. We use the word "object". @Ashish Hash code has nothing to do with memory management. Having the same hash code does not mean they are the same object. They are just two objects with the same hash code. I think your confusion comes from the fact that the default implementation of `hashCode` is to return the object's memory location.

Comment: That I understand we don't need worry about the memory management , since it is taking care by garbage collection of api. But as a programmer we should know how it is creating memory for object.

Comment: @Ashish the JVM creates memory for objects.